# How to store in-built function names in a Vector and parse through a loop in R

Tags: r, function

I am new to R and need some help.

I want to calculate the mean, median, etc. through a For Loop, for every column in the dataframe `df`. These functions are stored in vector `my_func`. I am not able to convert the variable stored in vector `my_func` to excute the function which is intended. I am adding the stats to the bottom of the dataframe:

```
my_func=c("mean", "median", "stats::sd", "max", "min")

for (func in my_func){
  new_row <- c()

  for (i in names(df)){
    y <- func(df[ ,i], na.rm=F)
    new_row <- c(new_row, y)
  }
  df[nrow(df)+ 1, ] = c(new_row[1:11])
  rownames(df)[nrow(df)] <- j
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store functions in a vector without the quotes:

```
my_func <- c(mean, median, stats::sd, max, min)
```

Then it should work. Just note that `my_func` will turn into a list.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the functions as suggested by @KarolisKoncevicius is probably the best solution, but another way to do it is to retrieve the functions by name before calling them.  Since one of your functions is defined by the expression `stats::sd` rather than just the name, you should parse the expression and use `eval()` to get the functions.

Your sample code also has a couple of other problems:  it refers to `j` without defining it, and it assumes there are 11 entries in `new_row`, when there could be any number.  This code fixes both problems and shows the parse and eval solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))

my_func=c("mean", "median", "stats::sd", "max", "min")

for (func in my_func){
  new_row <- c()
  f <- eval(parse(text=func))
  for (i in names(df)){
    y <- f(df[ ,i], na.rm=F)
    new_row <- c(new_row, y)
  }
  df[nrow(df)+ 1, ] <- new_row
  rownames(df)[nrow(df)] <- func
}

df
#>                   x           y
#> 1          1.000000 -2.27557495
#> 2          2.000000 -0.31151886
#> 3          3.000000 -0.87811049
#> 4          4.000000 -1.69935663
#> 5          5.000000  0.76985473
#> 6          6.000000 -0.70577880
#> 7          7.000000  1.46104332
#> 8          8.000000  1.34460671
#> 9          9.000000 -0.51577892
#> 10        10.000000  0.02118427
#> mean       5.500000 -0.27894296
#> median     5.500000 -0.31151886
#> stats::sd  2.738613  1.10605560
#> max       10.000000  1.46104332
#> min        1.000000 -2.27557495
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Karolis Koncevičius' solution works well. Your solution is also very good! I can use the same vector with "eval(parse(text=func))". Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut:  The only advantage of my answer is that it makes setting the row names in the result easier.  The last line in the outer loop would not work with his approach (unless he changed `my_func` to include the names as well as the functions, and used those).

Comment: This may indeed be useful.